# What C++ IDEs are available for iPhone?

Tags: iphone, software-recommendation, development

I really love my iPhone, and much as possible, I want to do everything from there.

I'm a software engineering student and, when I'm away from my PC, I'm planning to use my iPhone as my programming machine (meaning that I want to program directly on my iPhone).

Are there any available IDEs for iPhone that will let me program in C++?

Comment: I'd recommend an SSH app like Panic's Prompt to connect to a machine via ssh and then `screen` for multiple terminals and `vim` with the `zanus` suite for the "IDE". With a BT keyboard to the iPhone it's workable -- though you might go blind squinting at the screen. :)

Comment: I'm not sure if you really asked what you meant to ask. Du you want an IDE (code editor, reference, compiler, linker, debugger) or just a code editor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no native IDE available for iOS. Apple restricts unsigned code from being run on all iOS devices, thus making an IDE on iOS impossible. (this is possible on android to run code directly on the device that is written on device)

Your best bet is to get a regular text editor such as [nimbus](http://nimbustouch.com/) or anything that can checkout documents and edit them from git, svn or dropbox. You will never be able to run this code on iOS, so you will need to push it to your repository and compile and run it via a remote desktop client or via a SSH terminal.

To really fully automate this process you would have to edit your code, push it to the repository, compile it on another machine and then have that compiled binary shipped to your device using a distribution mechanism like [testflightapp](http://testflightapp.com) via a series of scripts (test flight has an API for this). It's not impossible, just hard.

Another option is to use a remote desktop client and remote to an IDE on a PC to edit and run your code there.

Answer (score -2):

Yeah,
There is c++ ide in AppStore. But the problem is that it is paid app.there are around 3 or 4 c++ ide. Some of the ide are cppcode,codetogo,c++ ide.

Comment: It would be nice if you could provide links to the App Store for the apps you mention. On a side note, I'm not sure why it is a "problem" that an app is a paid app. If it is a good app, why would it be bad to support the developer? Nobody owes you anything.